# Converting string into different variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a function that outputs a string that is always formatted "Month Day, Year".
With this, I'm looking to be able to convert the string into three variables. One for month, one for day, and one for year. The project is jQuery based, so if there is a more elegant solution that way, I would appreciate it.

Update:
Here is some of the code that i'm using. Before today, I wrote a function that used select options to choose the month, date, and year. Now I've changed to a simpler solution that uses a single text input in the format "Month Day, Year".

So now when I submit the form, instead of being able to use

```
var sm = smonth.value;
var sd = sday.value;
var sy = syear.value;
```

I only have one variable as

```
var sdate = sdate.value;
```

And what I'd like to do is be able to convert the sdate value (which is just the Month Day, Year string), back to the sm (Selected Month), sd (Selected Day), and sy (Selected Year) values.

Comment: Have a look at the `split` function.

Comment: You could return an array, or a object with those values.

Comment: 1. What's your question? 2. Can you post some of your code? It's hard to judge whether a solution is more elegant if there's no basis for comparison.

Comment: Updated the question with some clearer formatting and some code snippets. Sorry it's so vague!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or some like this:

```
var sdate = "Month Day, Year";
sdate = sdate.split(" ");
var sm = sdate[0];
var sd = sdate[1].substr(0, sdate[1].length-1);
var sy = sdate[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

use the javascript string functions.

```
    var test = "Jan 21, 2011";
    var firstbreak = test.indexOf(" ");
    var secondbreak = test.lastIndexOf(" ");
    var month = test.substr(0, firstbreak);
    var day = test.substr(firstbreak + 1, secondbreak - firstbreak-2);
    var year = test.substring(secondbreak + 1);
    alert(month + " " + day + ", " + year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split(' ')`, or a RegExp.

```
var aMatches = sdate.match(/^\b(\w+)\b (\d+), (\d+){2,4)$/gi);
```